# How to get CGridView total records in afterAjaxUpdate (yii)

Tags: javascript, yii, yii1.x

```
this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
         'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
         'filter'=>$model,
         'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'function(id, data){debugger;}',
         'template'=>'{items}{summary}{pager}',
```

On filter, I want to count number of result rows inside afterAjaxUpdate function so that i can use certain condition to hide and show my btn (somewhere in the page)

Is there any way to get that total rows??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the afterAjaxUpdate function you can make an ajax request to the server to return the number of records

Comment: Except ajax request is there any other solution?